# Raspberry: USB to RS232 (FT4232H chip) can't communicate with Device via Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, serial-port

I want to set up my serial connection to a pump with a USB to 4xRS232 (FT4232H chip). However, my serial connection can't write output from the pump. The whole setup works with a single usb to rs232 converter but not with my USB to 4xRS232 converter. My raspberry recognizes all 4 USB ports:

```
/dev/ttyAMA0: ttyAMA0 [fe201000.serial]
/dev/ttyUSB1: FT4232H Device
/dev/ttyUSB2: FT4232H Device
/dev/ttyUSB3: FT4232H Device
/dev/ttyUSB4: FT4232H Device
```

My code to write and read information with my external device looks as following:

import serial
import time

```
global ser
ser = serial.Serial() 
ser.port = '/dev/ttyUSB1'
#ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS
ser.parity = serial.PARITY_NONE
ser.stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE
ser.open()
encoding='utf-8'   

def pump_loop():    
    if ser.inWaiting() == 0:
        out_press=''
        ser.write(b'PRESSURE?\r')
        time.sleep(.1)
        #print(ser.in_waiting)
        #print(ser.read())
        while int(ser.in_waiting) > 0:
            out_press += str(ser.read(1), encoding)
            print(out_press)

pump_loop()
```

Edit: Cable set-up is the following: raspberry-usb--> FT4232H --> 4 RS232 --> female-to-female coupling --> pump

Comment: This should be straight forward. The usb ports are supposed to behave like any other connection. Is there a product you use for the FT4232H or did you build the circuit yourself?

Comment: Not quite sure if I am allowed to post links here, but that's the following product:
https://de.assmann.shop/de/Computer-und-Office-Zubehoer/Computer-Zubehoer/USB-Komponenten-und-Zubehoer/Schnittstellen-Adapter/USB-2-0-zu-4xRS232-Kabel.html?listtype=search&searchparam=rs232

Comment: First, I thought it might be a driver problem, but the FT4232H should be supported by the standard driver.   Can I assume that you had this running in an endless loop to be sure that it's not just a delay problem?

Comment: That's what I also red, the FT4232 is supported by the standard ftdi driver. It is an endless loop yes.

Comment: Closed: had to swap PIN 2 and 3 before using the female-female coupler, as they are swapped inside.

Comment: Interessting, that is a rather specific gender changer then. Usually they are straight 1-1 connected. If I remeber right this would be used to peer two clients together with a null modem cable. Anyways, thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Closed: had to swap PIN 2 and 3 before using the female-female coupler, as they are swapped inside.